# C++ converting character in vector to an integer...tough, need help?

Tags: c++

This is what I have:

```
char userInput;
int position;
vector<string> userVector(7);
vector<int> someVector(7,1);

cin >> userInput;
cin >> position;

if(userInput == 'X')
   userVector[position] = '1';

if(userVector[position]-someVector[position] == 0)
   cout << "Success"
```

My problem is that `userVector[position]` is actually a character, because `userVector` is a string vector.  However, I need this calculation to take place `(userVector[position] - someVector[position])` because I need to determine if the outcome is 0 or some other number.  Any help?

In case it doesn't make sense here, userVector HAS to be a string vector, because it's part of the requirements for this program.  Basically, a user is supposed to be allowed to enter an "X" anywhere in the userVector vector, and you have to tell them if it matches expected outputs.

So, in this case, the "expected output" would be someVector, which has a 1 in all of it's spaces.  What I'm trying to do is subtract the two vectors so that if the user enters anything other than X, the vector subtraction will not equal 0, and consequently, result in the program doing something different.

Hope that clears things up!

Comment: That should be `if( userInput == 'X' )`, I suppose (`==` vs. `=`)?

Comment: You should state what you are trying to achieve together with your approach. It is hard to determine what is correct or wrong or suggest alternatives if the problem is undefined. In this particular case, what is the format of your input? (I can only guess that `userVector` should probably not be `vector<string>`, but I cannot suggest whether it would be better to use `vector<int>` or `vector<char>`... for example.

Comment: @David, just cleared the problem up, hope that helps!

Comment: Still, why don't you explain the program? It cannot be that long... what are the inputs and the expected outputs? Is the user meant to introduce a single string? a number of strings? Do you want to report success whenever one of the elements is *guessed* or only when all of them are? if the latter, what will you report if only half of the inputs are correct? (BTW, I still am not sure that you need a `vector<string>` that structure contains *multiple* strings, do you need multiple strings or just one?...)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your code, you are trying to convert a string representing a decimal number into an integer. You have several ways of doing that; e.g., by using `istringstream`:

```
int num;
if (!(istringstream(userInput[position]) >> num))
    num = 0;
if (n - someVector[position] == 0) {
   ...
```

or you could use good old `atoi`:

```
if (atoi(userInput[position].c_str()) - someVector[position] == 0) {
```

If I am wrong about what you are trying to do, please clarify what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what you're trying to do from your statement of the
problem.    The expression `userInput[position]` isn't legal, since
`userInput` isn't a pointer, nor anything that can be converted to a
pointer.

But your code doesn't seem to correspond to the textual description,
since you describe `userInput` as a string vector
(`std::vector<std::string>`?), but the code declares it as a `char`.

Comment: Sorry, I feel really dumb, I just fixed my code up.  Hope that clears up the confusion.  Sorry again.

Comment: You're still confusion characters (type `char`) and strings (type `std::string`).  `'X'` or `'1'` are character constants, with type `char`; `"X"` or `"1"` are string constants, with type `char const[]` (which converts implicitly to `char const*` or `std::string` if needed).  `char` is also an integral type, so can be added and subtracted from and to `int`; if the value of the `char` is actually a character encoding, however, the results may not be what you expect: the character encoding of `'1'` on most systems is 49.  If you know that the character is a digit, then `c - '0'` is its value.